# Fixed position navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that I would like to keep at a fixed position (top), on my website. I would also like for the navigation bar to have some transparency. I applied the transparency to the navigation bar, which also makes any content (child elements) inside that div also inherit the transparency. So, to solve that I applied a relative position to the content inside of the navigation bar, but now the content that is supposed to appear fixed (inside the navigation bar) scrolls with the rest of the page content. How can I fix this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUfFT/5/)

Comment: use a transparent background-image instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use opacity in this case, use `RGBa` for the `background` of the navigation bar `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);` (and `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#0F000000, endColorstr=#0F000000);` for IE 8 and older). All children inherit the `opacity` value and there is nothing you can do to about it (except setting the parent's `opacity` back to `1` again, in which case you won't have semi-transparency on the parent anymore).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/CUfFT/8/) (changed back to original structure with navigation content inside navigation container and RGBa)

[**Demo#2**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/CUfFT/7/) (uses current structure and `opacity`, changed position for navigation content to `fixed`)

Comment: It is not actually a child anymore.

Comment: It's not supported by IE8 and older, where you can use a gradient filter to achieve the exact same effect as RGBa.

Comment: Better to use transparent image as a background

Comment: Why? This is 2012, not 2008. Excepting IE8 and older, for which you have the filter option which helps you achieve identical results, RGBa has excellent support and has been a better solution than images for at least two years. An image means another request. RGBa is just one line in the CSS.

Comment: @Matt: I was thinking you could go back to the original structure with `#nav-content` inside `#nav-container` (which also makes more sense) combined with the semi-transparent background. If you wish to keep the current structure, you just have to change `position: relative` to `position: fixed` and that solves the scroll problem. But, as I've said before, it makes more sense to have the content inside the container and not adjacent to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another transparency rule into your CSS for the elements inside the nav bar, to override the one which they inherit from the bar? Changing the position attribute shouldn't be necessary, I don't see how this will affect transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS pseudo selector `:children` and set the opacity to 1. This will make all the children of that element opaque.